# Is there a more efficient one liner to initialize a variable based on a condition?

Tags: python

Can the `atype` variable be initialized via a one liner ?

```
def detect(dt,result):
    """ prints the type of date """
    atype = 'unknown'
    if 'greg' in result:
        atype = 'Gregorian'
    elif 'eth' in result:
        atype = 'Ethiopian'

    print '%s is in %s format.' % (dt,atype)
```

Comment: This code is totally fine. There is no need at all to change it. Remember the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): *Readability counts.*

Comment: I disagree very slightly, @Space_CowbOy — it is slightly obscure to set the variable and then to have a conditional that maybe resets it but maybe leaves it alone. The assignment `atype = 'unknown'` should properly be put in a final `else:` clause of his `if` statement. He is trying to save one line, and getting slightly unclear code as a result.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y I also disagree but not for the same reason. It is because your writing oblige the function to execute an assignement atype = 'unknown' even when it will be useless, so there will be cases in which atype will be assigned two times. It is also slightly obscure, yes, but so slightly...

Answer (score 4):

You could use a pair of conditional expressions — and no parenthesis are necessary at all; just like Python knows that `1 + 2 + 3` should be done reasonably from left-to-right, so conditional expressions can be written with one clause after another without any fear of the interpreter getting confused. Line breaks and indentation are important for readability, however, so I generally do something like this:

```
atype = ('Gregorian' if 'greg' in result
         else 'Ethiopian' if 'eth' in result
         else 'unknown')
```

This form of indentation is not only the one that most editors will produce in any case if you press "enter" before each `else`, but it makes a great deal of visual sense to me when I come back later and read my own, or someone else's, code ­— which is, after all, a big reason we use Python, right? :)

**Edit:** Of course I realize that this is a one-liner only in the sense that Python sees the continued line as a single line of code; so I guess my answer is that your program would seem a bit dense to me as one *physical* line of Python, but works quite nicely to my eyes if written as one *logical* line of Python!

**Edit:** One further note: of course, I recognize that my code snippet violates PEP-8, which says to end continued lines with operators — so PEP-8 would have me move the `else` words up to the ends of the previous lines. I can only say that this is one of the rules of PEP-8 that I disagree with, which I regularly break, and that therefore I produce more readable code as a result. I think my difference with PEP-8 on this point comes from having a math typesetting background, and, as Donald Knuth emphasizes in the TeXBook, “displayed formulas always break *before* binary operations and relations” (p.195).

Comment: I agree with all your points. Except that in this case, and only in this case, I prefer to break lines after the 'else' keywords because I prefer to have all the possibilities ('Gregorian','Ethiopian','unknow') vertically aligned. But when I write instructions with '+' or '-' for ex., I prefer to break the line **before** the signs. In this latter case, the physical lines contain elements that are "dependent" since they are sumed, while in case of an alternative of several options, the elements are "independent" (and the conditions must be mutually exclusive)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is meaningful and readable...

```
atype = 'Gregorian' if 'greg' in result else ('Ethiopian' if 'eth' in result else 'unknown')
```

Comment: Nesting conditional operators is an atrocity.

Comment: @delnan: I disagree -- see @Brandon's answer.

Comment: @delnan I agree with martineau. What is so atrocious in this writing ? Without explanation, I find this judgement subjective

Comment: @eyquem: (1) It makes the line easily too long (yes, "too long" is somewhat subjective, but with two levels of indentation this small example is already over 100 characters - now use more complex expressions and you can reach 150+ chars). (2) Break it into several lines and you don't save much space compared to the if-statement version (as shown by OP). (3) I for one have a harder time deciphering the precedence (and therefore meaning) of nested conditional operators than following two simple `if` statements. As they aren't exactly common, I wouldn't be surprised if many had the same problem.

Comment: @delnan As Brandon Craig Rhodes in his answer, I think that it's more important to have a one-logical-liner than a one-space-liner. So I don't find that the solution of Drake Guan is a problem. I don't find that a one-logical-liner breaked in several lines is a problem as long as the one-logical-liner nature is easily perceived without having to spend a long time to decipher it. By the way, as soon as someone has became accustomed enough seeing several such writings, he decipher them without delay at first sight.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, on a forum, I propose

```
def detect(dt,result):
    """ prints the type of date """
    style = 'Gregorian' if 'greg' in result else\
            'Ethiopian' if 'eth'  in result else\
            'unknown'
    print '%s is in %s format.' % (dt,style)
```

and in the secret of my codes where nobody will come to see if I respect the Zen of Python, I would do in fact:

```
def detect(dt,result):
    """ prints the type of date """
    print dt + ' is in %s format.'\
          % \
          'Gregorian' if 'greg' in result else\
          'Ethiopian' if 'eth'  in result else\
          'unknown'
```

I measured execution's times: the second runs in 89 % of the time of the first

.

### EDIT 1

The test I conducted didn't satisfy me, in the end, because it isn't fair to compare a program in which an assignement is done (style = etc) to a program in which there is no equivalent assignement.

So I tested again, with modified codes.To accentuate the influence of differences between the codes, I added some lines of conditions.

I ran the following programs separately (to avoid possible persistence of objects that would be reassigned without having to be re-created; I don't precisely know what happens in the memory and the object model of Python, and if it may happen in fact; but I sometimes observe strange phenomenons when I measure execution's time. So I take no risk, I separate the codes)

first program

```
from time import clock

A=[]

for repeat in xrange(5000):
    def detect(dt,result):
        if 'greg' in result:
            h = '%s is in %s format.' % (dt,'Gregorian')
        elif 'eth' in result:
            h = '%s is in %s format.' % (dt,'Ethiopian')
        elif 'ame' in result:
            h = '%s is in %s format.' % (dt,'American')
        elif 'rus' in result:
            h = '%s is in %s format.' % (dt,'Russian')
        elif 'egyp' in result:
            h = '%s is in %s format.' % (dt,'Egyptian')
        else:
            h = '%s is in unknown format.' % dt

    te = clock()
    for i in xrange(10000):
        detect('zozo',' he is egyptolog')
    A.append(clock() - te)

print min(A)
```

second program

```
from time import clock

B=[]

for repeat in xrange(5000):


def detect(dt,result):
    x  = '%s is in %s format.' % (dt,'Gregorian' if 'greg' in result else\
                                  'Ethiopian' if 'eth'  in result else\
                                  'American' if 'ame'  in result else\
                                  'Russian' if 'rus'  in result else\
                                  'Egyptian' if 'egyp'  in result else\
                                  'unknown')

te = clock()
for i in xrange(10000):
    detect('zozo',' he is egyptolog')
B.append(clock() - te)

print min(B)
```

third program

```
from time import clock

C = []

for repeat in xrange(1000):
    def detect(dt,result):
        y = dt + ' is in %s format.'\
            % \
            'Gregorian' if 'greg' in result else\
            'Ethiopian' if 'eth'  in result else\
            'American' if 'ame'  in result else\
            'Russian' if 'rus'  in result else\
            'Egyptian' if 'egyp'  in result else\
            'unknown'

    te = clock()
    for i in xrange(10000):
        detect('zozo',' he is egyptolog')
    C.append(clock() - te)

print min(C)
```

.

I obtained

> 0.0198832 seconds
>
> 0,019962 seconds
>
> 0,012664 seconds

Conclusions:

- there is no difference between the way of writing the code with if-elif-else conditions or with if-else-else-else successive conditions.

  Then, even if the second manner isn't so atrocious than delnan think, it is slightly less immediately understandable, so I finally find that the first manner of writing is better than the second one because of the perfect readibility, without loosing any amount of performance.

  Use of if-else-else is interesting and the only solution in certain cases, when it is impossible to use if-elif-else, for exemple in a list comprehension or to write a lambda function.
- this time, my code runs in 64 % the time of the two other execution's times. The more there are conditions to examine, the faster is my code

  If someone is concerned by performance, this solution is the one to use. If not, a succession of if-elif-else conditions appears to me the best choice.

.

### EDIT 2

@eat,

Suppose that a list of one million elements, like this one

```
li = [('greg','Gregorian'),('eth','Ethiopian')]
```

has been recorded in serialized format with cPickle. Then the code will be:

```
import cPickle  

with open('trynewline.txt','r') as f:
    li = cPickle.load(f)

def detect(dt,result):
    for a,b in li:
        if a in result:
            return '%s is in %s format.' % (dt,b)
        else:
            return '%s is in unknown format.' % dt
```

or

```
import cPickle  

with open('trynewline.txt','r') as f:
    li = cPickle.load(f)

def detect(dt,result):
    ha = [ b for a,b in li if a in result]
    y = dt + ' is in %s format.'\
        % (ha[0] if ha else 'unknown')
```

That's all. Anyway, the data contained in **li** must come from somewhere. It can be  automatically produced; or it is manually produced. If it is manually produced and nobody created before me, I will be obliged to write manually the one million conditions myself. And if it is you that will have to write the code, you will do that also. I don't see how you could avoid it with your dictionary.

Comment: If you have only few conditions to test this will be fine, but problematic (as OP's code) when trying to handle 'clean way' much more conditions. Thanks

Comment: @eat I don't think so. See my edit, I added lines of conditions and it didn't became horrible

Comment: @eyquem: I'm sorry but IMHO your code already starts to look unnecessarily verbose. A side issue is with your timings; firstly) I don't believe that OP was asking such things, secondly) but if you are anyway trying to do realiable timings, please use module `timeit`. Thanks

Comment: @eat There was a time, I used exclusively **timeit** to measure execution's times. But each time, I was having difficulties to recall how to write the arguments, and it took more time to write a measure with **timeit** than with the simple **clock()** function. Moreover, and precise reason I let **timeit**, I realized that for the kind of simple measure I was doing , **clock()** has a sufficient precision. If two codes haven't notable difference in execution's times measured by **clock()**, it isn't the use of **timeit** that would change anything. If different enough, **clock()** is OK.

Comment: @eat I don't see where it is verbose. The OP didn't explicitly ask about performance, but I search reasons to choose one solution preferably to another. Now I have conclusions I hadn't before.

Comment: For timing related issues: please do not try to reinvent the wheel. timeit is the way to go, especially with proper ide, like IPython. Well, for the the verbose one: just assume that you have one million conditions to test ;-). Thanks

Comment: @eat Reinventing the wheel ? I reinvent nothing, I simply use a function simple to use: importing **clock**, and the call **clock()**, that's all. I don't create another **clock()** function. / And you, if you have one million conditions to test, how will you do to define the dictionary **types** ? If the data isn't available elswhere , you will have to write each instruction like ``types['greg']= 'Gregorian'`` manually. And if the data is somewhere ( a list, a file,...) I will do like you , I will manage to modify my code in order to include the data automatically, not manually

Comment: @eyquem: As such your timings aren't reliable, please see http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html for more details. Obviously there has to be a programmable way to create the mappings of `conditions` to `actions`! I just described a way to to utilize such a mapping. So, you see, my whole point is that you can't create a reasonable expressions to simultaneously map a `condition` to `action`, while 'executing' it. Thanks

Comment: @eat Give me a full executable code as-is that proves that my use of clock() leads me to important variation or uncertainty in the execution's times. I am a bit lazy. I did this work of comparison in the past and I concluded that **timeit** hasn't any advantage for me for the little comparisons I can do with clock()

Comment: @eyquem: Now you have a new solution, which may be quite inefficient. Anyway the dictionary based solution would be populated only once and then accessed in O(1) time. Feel free to use your timings, but I wouldn't pollute my code with explicit timing instructions. There are perfectly valid tools for that purpose. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yep, Python's variable's scope is a bit different than in other programming languages. 
So,

```
if 'greg' in result:
    atype = 'Gregorian' 

print(atype)
```

Will do just fine. Also

```
if 'greg' in result: atype = 'Gregorian'
print(atype)
```

Will work, unless it's a Python shell (you have to execute the whole script)

But anyway, it's a bad practice to make very long, condition-dependent variable initializations.

Answer (score 0):

actually strange but..it's just a different way to do it..I think it is easier to extend, but i guess there is a better way ;)

```
import operator as op
import functools as fc

atype = {'greg':'Gregorian', 'eth':'Ethiopian'}.get(filter(fc.partial(op.contains, ('greg', 'eth')), res)[0], 'unknown')
```

Comment: You probably wanted `import functools as fc` here too.

Answer (score 0):

Although there's a separate line to set up a dictionary, here's an a one-liner (spread over two for readability):

```
typemap = {'greg': 'Gregorian', 'eth': 'Ethiopian'}

atype = ([typemap[frag] for frag in typemap if frag in result][0]
         if any(frag in result for frag in typemap) else 'unknown')
```

Comment: Sorry, but this time I dislike. Endeavouring to obtain a one-liner, that leads to an unreadable instruction.

Comment: @eyquem: True, the `[typemap[frag] for frag in typemap if frag in result][0]` part *is* a bit awkward, but I think the rest is fairly readable.